# Source of the 1953 revisions to "The Great Gatsby"

Tags: textual-history, f-scott-fitzgerald, the-great-gatsby

The 1953 Scribner’s edition of *The Great Gatsby* has many minor differences in wording from the first (1925) edition by the same publisher. I’ve collected some of the differences from the first fifty pages or so in the table below, to give you a sense of the changes. Italics indicate words that appear in one edition but not the other.

| # | 1925 edition | # | 1953 edition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [6](https://archive.org/details/the-great-gatsby_202101/page/6/mode/2up) | a source of perpetual *wonder* to the gulls that fly overhead. To the wingless a more *interesting* phenomenon | [5](https://archive.org/details/greatgatsby0000fsco/page/4/mode/2up) | a source of perpetual *confusion* to the gulls that fly overhead. To the wingless a more *arresting* phenomenon |
| [18](https://archive.org/details/the-great-gatsby_202101/page/18/mode/2up) | “This Mr. Gatsby you spoke of is my neighbor—” I *began*. | [15](https://archive.org/details/greatgatsby0000fsco/page/14/mode/2up) | “This Mr. Gatsby you spoke of is my neighbor—” I *said*. |
| [27](https://archive.org/details/the-great-gatsby_202101/page/26/mode/2up) | a transcendent effort, of *ash-gray* men, who move dimly | [23](https://archive.org/details/greatgatsby0000fsco/page/22/mode/2up) | a transcendent effort, of men who move dimly |
| [28](https://archive.org/details/the-great-gatsby_202101/page/28/mode/2up) | he turned up in popular *cafés* with her | [24](https://archive.org/details/greatgatsby0000fsco/page/24/mode/2up) | he turned up in popular *restaurants* with her |
| [30](https://archive.org/details/the-great-gatsby_202101/page/30/mode/2up) | she carried her flesh sensuously | [25](https://archive.org/details/greatgatsby0000fsco/page/24/mode/2up) | she carried her *surplus* flesh sensuously |
| [33](https://archive.org/details/the-great-gatsby_202101/page/32/mode/2up) | Fifth Avenue, warm and soft, almost pastoral, on the summer Sunday afternoon. I wouldn’t have | [28](https://archive.org/details/greatgatsby0000fsco/page/28/mode/2up) | Fifth Avenue, *so* warm and soft, almost pastoral, on the summer Sunday afternoon *that* I wouldn’t have |
| [35](https://archive.org/details/the-great-gatsby_202101/page/34/mode/2up) | When I came back they had *both* disappeared | [29](https://archive.org/details/greatgatsby0000fsco/page/28/mode/2up) | When I came back they had disappeared |
| [42](https://archive.org/details/the-great-gatsby_202101/page/42/mode/2up) | I tried to show by my expression that I *expected no affection*. | [35](https://archive.org/details/greatgatsby0000fsco/page/34/mode/2up) | I tried to show by my expression that I *had played no part in her past*. |
| [42](https://archive.org/details/the-great-gatsby_202101/page/42/mode/2up) | one day when he was out: ‘Oh, is that your suit? | [35](https://archive.org/details/greatgatsby0000fsco/page/34/mode/2up) | one day when he was out.” *She looked around to see who was listening.* “‘Oh, is that your suit?’ |
| [44](https://archive.org/details/the-great-gatsby_202101/page/44/mode/2up) | I wiped from his cheek the spot of dried lather | [37](https://archive.org/details/greatgatsby0000fsco/page/36/mode/2up) | I wiped from his cheek the *remains of the* spot of dried lather |
| [48](https://archive.org/details/the-great-gatsby_202101/page/48/mode/2up) | hair *bobbed* in strange new ways | [40](https://archive.org/details/greatgatsby0000fsco/page/40/mode/2up) | hair *shorn* in strange new ways |
| [57](https://archive.org/details/the-great-gatsby_202101/page/56/mode/2up) | “‘Weren’t you in the *First* Division during the war?” “Why, yes. I was in the *Twenty-eighth Infantry*.” “I was in the *Sixteenth* | [47](https://archive.org/details/greatgatsby0000fsco/page/46/mode/2up) | “‘Weren’t you in the *Third* Division during the war?” “Why, yes. I was in the *ninth machine-gun battalion*.” “I was in the *Seventh Infantry* |
| [58](https://archive.org/details/the-great-gatsby_202101/page/58/mode/2up) | the whole *eternal* world | [48](https://archive.org/details/greatgatsby0000fsco/page/48/mode/2up) | the whole *external* world |
| [60](https://archive.org/details/the-great-gatsby_202101/page/60/mode/2up) | above the *chatter* of the garden | [50](https://archive.org/details/greatgatsby0000fsco/page/50/mode/2up) | above the *echolalia* of the garden |

F. Scott Fitzgerald died in 1940, so it seems unlikely that he participated in the publication process for the 1953 edition. Where, then, did these revisions come from?

Comment: The full text of the two editions together with images of the scanned pages are also available on https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Great_Gatsby . Accessing the text there may be more convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Princeton University Library provides scans of Fitzgerald's own copy of the first edition with corrections in his hand: [*The Great Gatsby* corrected first edition](https://findingaids.princeton.edu/catalog/C0187_c00020). I checked only some of those against your table and they match. So, it appears that the 1953 edition incorporates Fitzgerald's corrections.

Comment: This explains all the changes in the first 59 pages, but oddly not *chatter* ⟶ *echolalia* (p. 60).